# Uploading files to S3 via AWS CloudFront with OAI Using S3 Pre-signed URLs: Missing S3 Metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently working on implementing an upload system for my AWS Amplify-based website. The goal is to generate S3 pre-signed URLs for the purpose of uploading files to my S3 storage. Unfortunately, I cannot directly use S3 pre-signed URLs on the web client due to CORS restrictions. To overcome this, I'm attempting to set up rewrite rules on AWS Amplify to forward requests from CloudFront to S3.

Here's an example of the URL structure I'm working with:

```
https://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/upload/product/a1pos/20231005074611177.xlsx?s3 pre-signed params generated.....
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when I upload a file through CloudFront, the file is successfully uploaded, but the associated metadata is missing. I'm unsure whether this issue is related to the Origin Access Identity (OAI) permissions or if there's a specific CloudFront configuration needed to preserve metadata.

To provide context, when I use the original S3 pre-signed URL generated directly from S3, the uploads work perfectly and the metadata is retained. (Postman test)

Here's my S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-xxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-xxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity xxxxxxx"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Upload via S3 pre-signed URL directly:
[image: Used S3 pre-signed directly]

Using CloudFront URL metadata missed
[image]